# Clearcase "pname" for a VOB

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

I'm trying to change the ownership on a VOB, and I see that the `cleartool protect` command has a `chown` option.  It's asking for a pname, and I can't seem to find documentation on what a pname is or how to specify one.  I guess my questions boil down to:

1. What's a pname?  What's its format?
2. How do I specify the pname for a VOB?
3. Is there documentation on pnames somewhere?  Or at least examples of changing ownership of VOBs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the ownership of a Vob is done through **[`cleartool protectvob`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_protectvob.htm)**.

It will require the "`pname-in-vob`":

> The pathname of the VOB tag (whether or not the VOB is mounted) or of any file system object within the VOB (if the VOB is mounted).

I.e: `/vobs/MyVob` (unix-style) or `\MyVob` (usual Windows declaration for Vob tags)

---

It is different from [`cleartool protect`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_protect.htm), which would only protect an element (file or directory), which is, in the case of a Vob, the root directory of the Vob.
The path of that root directory would be the `pname`.
But again, that wouldn't change the ownership of the Vob.

Answer (score 1):

"pname" is a VOB path name.  An example element path name would be `M:\view1\vob3\src\main.c` or `/vob3/src/main.c` (depending on your platform).   `cleartool protect` changes permissions or ownership of a VOB object identified by its pathname